# Alternatives to Google Cloud Vision AI

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I'm creating an Android app which has to identify draws made by children. The structure of the draw is this:
[image]

I noticed that the Google Cloud Vision AI instrument can identify that the draw corresponds to an animal and this is exactly what I'm looking for. Since a child can draw and write what he wants (this means that texts and numbers are accepted) I understood that he could access to the paid features of the service. Are there instrument like this one which identify objects/human being and that can be implemented in Android?

Comment: I'm not getting the core question.  I think you started by saying that Cloud Vision AI seems to meet your needs.  Being a Google API, you should be able to invoke it from any source (such as an Android device) through a network API call.

Comment: @Kolban The procedure to try it is a bit more complicated, since I understood that to able to use its API you need to register to the Google Cloud platform and add a payment method. This is used to charge you if you try to scan image which contains texts etc.. I would like to avoid this, since I don't need all these features. I just need a method to identify (with not all this accuracy) what the child has drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Cloud Vision API allows one to submit an image and get back an interpretation of that image.  The data returned can contain a variety of sections.  At the highest level these are:

- Labels
- Text
- Document (OCR)
- Safe determination
- Face detection
- Landmark detection
- Logo detection
- Image properties
- Web similar images
- Cropping suggestions

When you supply an image, *you* have the choice of how many of these features are examined from the supplied image.  When you make the API call to process the image, you declare which (one, some or all) of the above are to be processed.  From your description, it sounds like you are looking for [label detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels) and nothing more.

Since Google has to run significant compute and other data processing work against the image, there is a charge for the service of interpreting an image.  Looking at the [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/pricing) we seem to see that Google charges in units of 1000 images.  There is a free tier which is 1000 images/month.  If you need to process less than this, then there should be no cost.  If you need to process more than 1000/month, it appears that the charges vary based upon the processing required.  For example, it appears to be $1.50 for every 1000/month above the first 1000/month that are free.  The price decreases automatically if you have very high volumes of images to process.  If you ONLY need label detection then when you submit an image for processing, ensure that is all that is requested in the API call. If you request additional interpretations of the image you will be billed for those in addition.